# Why isn't my python code seeing the condition?

Tags: python

My python code isn't working. I have tried many ways of doing it but I can't seem to make this work. Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
if not dead:
   time.sleep(2)
   print('')
   print('"Ok next question." She looked at a paper in front of her.')
   time.sleep(2)
   print('"Where on earth do they a day with 24 hours and a night with 24 hours?"')
   time.sleep(2)
if ally:
   print('')
   print('"Small hint, it starts with A and is a cold desert."')
   print('')
   answer = input('Which place?:')
 else:
   answer = input('Which place?:')
   if answer == 'Antarctica' or answer == 'antarctica':
      time.sleep(2)
      print('')
      print('She nods. "Correct. Two more.')
   if answer != 'Antarctica' and answer != 'antarctica' and ally:
      time.sleep(2)
      print('')
      print('Shaking her head with wide eyes, she looks around carefully.')
      time.sleep(2)
      print('"The answer is Antarctica." She says, mimicking your voice.')
      dead = False
      time.sleep(2)
      print(''"I can't do that much, so please try to refrain from getting it wrong."'')
   if answer != 'Antarctica' and answer != 'antarctica' and not ally:
      time.sleep(2)
      print('')
      print('She sighs. '"I'm sorry."' The fire below comes closer and closer as you fall.')
      dead = True
```

The code just seems to end if I put in a wrong answer, whereas I would like it to see that if the user has an ally, it will give out a different answer, if they don't have an ally they give a different answer etc. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Indentation is important in python.  Please fix the formatting of your question so it is identical to your code.

Answer (score 2):

A string can have only one value. What the user entered is either not 'Antarctica' or not 'antarctica'... it can *never* be both.

Since `and` has higher [operator precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) than `or`, your current statements are essentially this, further causing unexpected results.

```
if (answer != 'Antarctica') or (answer != 'antarctica' and ally):

if (answer != 'Antarctica') or (answer != 'antarctica' and not ally):
```

Use `and` instead of `or`:

```
if answer != 'Antarctica' and answer != 'antarctica' and ally:

if answer != 'Antarctica' and answer != 'antarctica' and not ally:
```

You could also take advantage of `elif` and `else` - there is no need to check the other conditions if one was already `true`.

Comment: It just finishes with Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

change

```
answer != 'Antarctica' or answer != 'antarctica'
```

to

```
answer.lower() != 'antarctica'
```

Comment: That is not the same thing. The result is very different between the two parts of your answer.